# Syntax error 1084: Expecting semicolon before leftbrace

Tags: actionscript

Did make a Flash banner and it all works fine. But when I want to put with the rectangle tool a button over the whole banner and put in the action tab the code:

```
Symbol16.onRelease() {
getURL('http://www.domainname.nl/');
}
```

I will get an error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 5', Frame 1, Line 1 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbrace
```

I've already searched for many hours to the solution but couldn't find anything on the web.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

If more info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a method by this way:

```
Symbol16.onRelease = function() {
getURL('http://www.domainname.nl/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your script version if you are on ActionScript **3.0**.

To do this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, **Flash** Tab → **Script: ActionScript 2.0** → Press **OK**.